# Create a tunnel with ngrok to connect to MongoDB local db

Tags: mongodb, express, ngrok

I would like to create a tunnel between two computer.

Computer 1 : Frontend (React)

Computer 2 : API with MongoDB local database and NodeJS backend server

I tried to use ngrok to create a tunnel between the two computer so my partner can test/build connection to the API. It does not work... Installation of ngrok has been done following the Get starting guide without a problem.

What we have done :

1. Create a copy of NodeJS on Computer 1.
2. On Computer 2, create a tunnel to expose MongoDB port (27017) with :

`ngrok http localhost:27017`

3. Modify the MongoDB connection string on Computer 1 to specify the ngrok link so it look like : 'mongodb://username:pwd@xxxxxx.ngrok.io/dbname?authSource=admin', (instead of 'mongodb://username:pwd@localhost:27017/dbname?authSource=admin',

The problem is : when we try to start the app (npm start) on Computer 1, it doesn't work.

```
Error : The app tries to connect to the db but fails.
{ MongoTimeoutError: Server selection timed out after 30000 ms
    at Timeout.setTimeout [as _onTimeout] (C:\Users\marin\Documents\Code\Codecademy\Site\Travel-kit\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\sdam\topology.js:897:9)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:436:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:300:5)
    at listOnTimeout (timers.js:263:5)
    at Timer.processTimers (timers.js:223:10)
  name: 'MongoTimeoutError',
  reason:
   { Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND http http:27017
       at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:56:26)
     name: 'MongoNetworkError',
     errorLabels: [ 'TransientTransactionError' ],
     [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} },
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }
```

-> Mongo service is running on computer 2. I can start the db and the app locally. Everything works normally.
-> Tunnel creation is normally working. If I try to to create a tunnel with port 3000 and run nodejs on Computer 2, I can send a request from Computer 1 and get the result normally.

The problem seems to be in the way I try to connect to the db directly.

**** SOLVED

The problem was that MongoDB uses tcp and not http, so the only thing I change is create a tunnel using :

```
ngrok tcp 27017
```

Comment: try this  ````ngrok http 27017````, you need to expose port number 27017 to use it on other computer. avoid adding localhost

Comment: I tried, I get the same kind of error with reason :  Error: connect ECONNREFUSED XX.XXX.XX.XXX:27017

Answer (score 4):

I managed to solve the problem myself.

The problem was that MongoDB uses tcp and not http, so the only thing I change is create a tunnel using :

```
ngrok tcp 27017
```